# Height of Irregular Pyramid Given it's Faces

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

Example of Flattened Irregular 5 Face Pyramid:

[image]

I have a series of flattened pyramids which I try to model in 3D.
All pyramids are either 4 or 5 faces + base. 
All use triangles combined from 3 fixed edge dimensions (30,36,42).

How can I find the height of these pyramids? Thanks,

Edit#1: Joseph, Thanks, but I don't think the tetrahedron solution can solve this. I probably wasn't clear enough but I have only the length of the perimeter edges and length to the pyramid vertex..and so don't have enough info to create the intermediate tetrahedrons.

Hopefully this image is clearer:
[image: Irregular Pyramid & known edges & faces]

Vertexes a-e are all on the same plane. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

First solve it for a tetrahedron, three lateral faces.
Call the three base vertices $a$, $b$, $c$, 
the apex vertex $v$,
and the lengths of the edges
from $a$ to $v$: $d_a$, $d_b$, $d_c$.
Now solve three equations simultaneously in the unknowns $x,y,z$:
\begin{eqnarray}
((x, y, z) - a) \cdot ({x, y, z} - a) &=& d_a^2 \\
((x, y, z) - b) \cdot ({x, y, z} - b) &=& d_b^2 \\
((x, y, z) - c) \cdot ({x, y, z} - c) &=& d_c^2 
\end{eqnarray}
In general you'll find two solutions, $\pm z$; take $z>0$.
This gives you $v$ :

---

[image: Tetra3D]

---

Now, in your case, you have either four or five lateral faces, which gives you
redundancy. Solve for all combinations of $\binom{4}{3}$ or $\binom{5}{3}$
inscribed tetrahedra and average the solutions for $v$. Of course they should all
be identical, but numerical errors will likely creep in.